# PostgreSQL: run many selects at one time

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, select, performance-testing

How is it possible to run e.g. 1000 queries at one time in postgreSQL? I would like to test performance and optimalization of my database. I want to run many selects and count time of running.

Comment: Yes, this should be possible.  However, 1,000 queries at one time is a lot of simultaneous usage.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Remember about configuration! max_connections setting may need to increase depending on your test case.

Comment: I apologize for bad question. I would like to know how is it possible? - see edited. Do I need to make multiple connections, or does there exist any tool for this?

Comment: You can use `pgbench` for that: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgbench.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pgbench` will be a good idea. First, create a sql file and put your test query inside. Then run the test bench in this way by replacing SQLFilePath, UserName and DatabaseName to your version

```
pgbench.exe -c 10 -f SQLFilePath -j 10 -n -t 10 -U UserName DatabaseName
```

Here is the list of command that you can tweak

```
-c = number of concurrent database clients
-f = script file path
-j = number of threads (the clients are evenly distributed among this number of threads)
-n = don't run VACUUM (docs require it be set in case of custom a script)
-t = number of transactions each client makes
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it supports PostgreSQL load testing via [JDBC protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)

1. [Download Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and unpack it somewhere
2. Download [Postgres JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) and drop the .jar to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Run JMeter
4. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to Test Plan and specify the desired number of threads, test duration, ramp-up period there.
5. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) test element and specify connection details, credentials, other parameters there.
6. Add [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and set your query there
7. [Run your test](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#load_test_running)
8. Analyze results using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article for more information on databases load testing using Apache JMeter.